# iPhone simulator keeps status bar in view

Tags: ios, react-native

I have started using React Native for mobile development, and started with a simple Hello World example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>      
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason, the top bar in the iPhone simulator is not accounted for when rendering.  I have never done iPhone development, and I'm confused if this is normal or if there's a problem with my simulator.  I expect the "Hello World" to be display directly under the native top bar.  Is this expected?

[image: view over status bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should add a padding to your parent view to be equal to the status bar height.

Ideally you should create a screen Component that will add this padding and wrap all your inner screens with that screen Component

```
const ScreenWrapper = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={{paddingTop:30}}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Then you can do the following to any new screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  Image,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScreenWrapper>
        <View>
           <Text>Hello World</Text>
        </View>
      </ScreenWrapper>      
    );
  }
}
```